# First Ever Java Program Incorrect Output

Tags: java

Sorry for really stupid question, I'm learning a new language and taking this code:

```
public class Exercise01 {
    int i;
    char c;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Exercise01 E = new Exercise01();
        System.out.println("i = " + E.i);
        System.out.println("c = [" + E.c + "]");
    }
}
/* Output:
i = 0
c = [
*/
```

Why the output does not produce "]" character? Has it something to do with Unicode?

PostEdited: the variable E.c was not initialized for experimentation purpose.

Comment: It is produced on my side. Is this all the code?

Comment: It gives the expected output for me too.

Comment: @Sophie, I myself tested your code, I got the output exactly as desired ! Why don't you check it again ?

Comment: Dear all, thank you for feedback so far! I realized that the output was bad in Eclipse, while in the terminal it was fine (as expected).
Below we can see good answers, however I hope my question reminded many of you that primitive types (being class fields) indeed are initialized to the default values. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to print the null character as your `char c` hasn't need initialised. i.e. `\0` Interestingly you can't copy and paste this character easily as most C code sees this as an end of string marker.

I see the `]` when I run the code.

Try changing your code with

```
char c = '?';
```

gives me an output of

```
i = 0
c = [?]
```

---

One way to reproduce this problem is to run on unix

```
java Main | more
```

which outputs

```
i = 0
c = [
```

Comment: this is not a C question, this is a java question, and many users above including me  say they have got the output as expected !

Comment: The question is `Why the output does not produce "]" character?`  "It works for me" is not an answer. An interaction with a C program, is a possible answer.

Comment: `more` is a program written in C. Using it or something like it can cause a truncation of the output.

Answer (score 6):

It may be that the place your program is outputting to, a console or a window, is getting confused by the U+0000 character which is the value of E.c.

It works fine for me.

Initialize E.c and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Probably has to do with the fact that E.c isn't initialized to anything

Comment: JLS 4.12.5: `Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10): [...]For type char, the default value is the null character, that is, '\u0000'.`

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because `c` is not initialized and therefore holds `\0`, i.e. "end of line". So, `println` prints until end of line and does not print your `]`

Comment: -1 println does print the entire String. It may be the UI not displaying it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your **char C** as well as the **int i**. Good code practice: It is important to initialize your variable once you declare a variable!

Comment: Yes, it is a good practice, but take a look at answers elsewhere.